# Get the entity class name from the table name

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I would like to do the reverse of getting the table name from an entity:

**I want to get the entity name from a table name**, i.e. the name of the entity that is mapped to that table.

Same goes for the db column: how to get the field name of the entity that is mapped to it?

Comment: Let me see... if you have a table name, do you want to get the entity name related to it?

Comment: @manix yes (... bc this comment is too short)

Comment: i think, we can use naming strategy to convert table name to class name, if it was used for class naming from table names

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I was able to do, though it's not optimum because it goes through all entity class names registered:

```
/**
 * @param \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em Entity manager
 * @param string $table Table name
 * @return string Entity class name, null if not found
 */
protected function getClassNameFromTableName($em, $table)
{
    // Go through all the classes
    $classNames = $em->getConfiguration()->getMetadataDriverImpl()->getAllClassNames();
    foreach ($classNames as $className) {
        $classMetaData = $em->getClassMetadata($className);
        if ($table == $classMetaData->getTableName()) {
            return $classMetaData->getName();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em Entity manager
 * @param string $className
 * @param string $column
 * @return string Field name, null if not found
 */
protected function getFieldNameFromColumnName($em, $className, $column)
{
    $classMetaData = $em->getClassMetadata($className);
    if ($classMetaData) {
        return $classMetaData->getFieldForColumn($column);
    }
    return null;
}
```